# Should I use a custom hash function when using hash table in java with big data sets?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I'm making a concordance of a very large text with the help of hash table in Java. After learning a bit about how it works I've found out that to prevent corruption of the data a sufficiently good hash function is needed. Is the implementation of hash table in Java good enough for this? The data contains millions of words.

**EDIT**

```
    ArrayList<Integer> indexArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

    String line = bf.readLine();
    input = line.split(" ");

// Extract first word and it's index
    String word = input[0];
    String lastWord = word;
    int index = Integer.valueOf(input[1]);

// Time the execution of storing all data in hashmap
    double time = (double) System.currentTimeMillis();

    while((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    // Split line into words and store in variables
        input = line.split(" ");
        word = input[0];
        index = Integer.valueOf(input[1]);

        // If same word is encountered then add it's index to indexArray
        if (input[0].equals(lastWord)) {
            indexArray.add(index);

        // If different word is encountered then add the last word and 
    // it's index array to hashmap, finally reset relevant variables
        } else {
            hmap.put(word, indexArray);
            System.out.println(hmap.hashCode());
            indexArray.clear();
            indexArray.add(index); // Add last index to the reset indexArray
            lastWord = word;       // Set last word to newly found word
        }
    }
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time)/1000);
```

Comment: "prevent corruption of the data a sufficiently good hash function is needed" How excatly did you "find out" that? Because it's not true at all. Hash function doesn't affect data corruption. Broken code can corrupt your data, but not an ineffective hash function.

Comment: Oh, well my impression is that some elements in the hash table might get the same hash number. Is that not correct?

Comment: HashMap deals with hash collisions. Of course, if hashCode() always returns the same value, the performance of the map operations will degrade from O(1) to O(n), but it will always be correct. The Map won't work correctly if your code (including the code inside hashCode) is incorrect, but that's another matter. What is the type of the keys in your HashMap? If it's a standard Java type that already has a hashCode() method, what makes you think a custom implementation of yours would make it more correct or efficient?

Comment: Ok. What I'm doing is that I use .put() to insert values from a textfile of sorted words into the hashtable. I'll post the code in edit.

Comment: So, you're storing Strings as keys. String has a perfectly functional and efficient hashCode implementation.

Comment: The hashCode of String should be sufficient. What exactly are you trying to do with this code? I'm confused why you have the indexArray and any reference to the previous word.

Comment: indexArray is for the index of the words in the text. Needed later for stuff that I'll do in the program. Seems like the current state of the program works well. Thanks!